# How to store two related documents in Sharepoint 2010 (365)

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I want to store a row that contains two "documents" (a blob and a PDF) along with some metadata about (such as completion date and client name).  What is the recommended way to do this in Sharepoint 2010/365?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't catch the BLOB thing.. but I think question is how to store multiple documents for one client , by entering metadata one time.

Answer is Document Set, basically its new content type inherited from Folder content type.
You can upload multiple documents in Document Set and metadata will get applied to all the documents in this set.

Comment: Sounds like that's the one!  Thanks, Sandeep.